# How to load XML file with headers as rows not tags?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Above Question can be a bit confusing but i'll try to clear the case here:

Configurations:

- Scala 2.10.6
- Spark Core 1.5.2
- Spark Sql 1.6.1
- spark-xml 0.3.2
- OS: Ubuntu 14.0
- IDE: Eclipse Mars

Input XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Address</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Hobby</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Anthony</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Sector 43</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Swimming</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">John</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Sector 2</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">cricket</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Alice</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">#43 park avenue</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">baseball</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
```

The above stated file is an XML file fed to Apache Spark SQL, now the problem is the headers of this XML file is stored as rows in

```
Row
```

tag and not as XML tags . By following tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NemEp53yGbI) and using the same code i get the schema as

The code used in scala is :

```
def loadDemographicdata(sqlcontext : SQLContext)={
  var df : DataFrame = null
  var seconddf : DataFrame = null
  import sqlcontext.implicits._

  df = sqlcontext.read
      .format("xml")
      .option("rowTag","Row")
      .load("DataSource/demographic.xml")

      df.printSchema()
}
```

```
The resultant schema is :

    root
    |-- @AutoFitHeight: long (nullable = true)
     |-- Cell: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- @Index: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Data: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- #VALUE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- @Type: string (nullable = true)
```

but what is required is that the first row headers constituent form the schema of the table and the way data is stored . How to achieve this 
Help!!

Comment: Well i have got a way out of this by converting first to csv and then loading into RDD as a Data Frame!!Still not a optimal way!! Search is on.